# GAE Sending emails via SMTP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Reading up on GAE as a possible alternative to dedicated hosting (or VPS)...

Seems I would need to re-write a bit of code, if I had modules which relied on SMTP. Does this mean that even if I connected to a remote SMTP server that code would need to change to an HTTP API (assuming one is even provided by an third party SMTP provider such as smtp.com).

Comment: Check out sockets: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

Comment: @Dimitry - PHP runtime does not support outgoing sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - AppEngine/PHP does not yet support sockets and thus you can not connect to external SMTP servers. Also, even with sockets you would not be able to use SMPT on port 25, but authenticated SMTP on port 587 - see [socket limitations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/#limitations-and-restrictions).

OTOH, you can send email from AppEngine via the [Mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/).

If you still want to send email via an external mail provider, you need to choose one that supports HTTP API, for example [Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html).

Comment: Or have a look at Sendgrid here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sendgrid

Comment: I googled SMTP REST API providers and found them actually...but the mailing classes with most PHP frameworks (SwiftMailer, Zend, etc) all probably coupled to sockets, so I would have to rework that code to use HTTP API or build something simpler to send emails with attachments I suppose...thanks again :)